# Find active API users

Tags: magento-1.9, api

Is there any (easy) way to find out which API users are still active? Or when a user was used the last time?

I just came up with add some logging code in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php
login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding some logging code. If someone has a better solution, please share.

```
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/User.php
@@ -202,6 +202,8 @@ class Mage_Api_Model_User extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
      */
     public function login($username, $apiKey)
     {
+        Mage::log("username: ".$username." apiKey: ".$apiKey,true,"api_active.log");
+        
         $sessId = $this->getSessid();
         if ($this->authenticate($username, $apiKey)) {
             $this->setSessid($sessId);
```

Comment: Since nobody has a better solution I'll mark my answer as accepted. Feel free to add your suggestion, if its better I'll switch. Thanks.